# Downloads over 2MB on Azure Linux Web App (PHP) fail

Tags: php, linux, azure

I've searched the last two hours for a solution to this problem, and have tried multiple suggestions found both here in StackOverflow and other sources. So if this is, indeed, addressed elsewhere I apologize before hand. But I need some serious help here.

**Current Working Environment:**

I have a PHP Web App developed for a customer that is currently hosted on a virtual Linux Server. The website handles DSGVO sensitive files uploaded by customers, and are therefore saved encrypted in a secured directory outside the website structure and is inaccessible from the internet.

In the Admin Area of the app my customer can download files as a .zip after logging in to the system. There is no direct download, and my customer only gets the file after the system verifies they are authorized to view the files. The size of the download file can be up to 64M, but we've been able to download everything without a single problem.

Currently I use the "classic" download script for downloading the file as shown below (condensed form, we've all pretty much used one version or another of this:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename( $zipfile ) );
header('Expires: 0');
header( 'Content-Length: ' . $zipFileSize );
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

readfile( $zipfile );
```

(NOTE: this is not complete, but I've included a snip of the code to show how things are currently running. There is alot more than this occurring before hand, security checks, build, encryption functions, etc., as well as in this snippet as well, but I think it's enough to show that the script, itself, is not the culprit. Or at least I hope so.)

**Current Situation:**

My customer is now on the Azure Bandwagon and has mandated that all of his websites (all PHP) are to moved to Azure. This morning we had finally truly believed we had accomplished the complete move and the last website, the one listed above, would be ready to be brought online this weekend.

Unfortunately, not.

During testing we found that any download request for a file over 2MB hangs fails. After a lot of searching, I've found that after a recent update that was pushed to the App Service Linux, file download has been restricted to 2MB. From my understanding, this was done at the Apache level (though this might not be correct).

I have tried many different "workarounds" but nothing works. I did find the following:

[Unable to download static content when using php images on Azure App Service - Linux](https://azureossd.github.io/2020/09/15/unable-to-download-static-content-php-on-azure-app-service-linux/index.html)

Unfortunately that doesn't work in our situation, as stated above the .zip files are extremely large and the system times out. If I set the set_time_limit to 0, it runs forever. I increased the chunk size in the fread() call dramatically, and for a 14.9MB file I get over 70K iterations before it times out (without the set_time_limit). I have tried everything I can find, but no success.

Has anyone had this problem? And the big question, what is the solution?

Any and all suggestions and help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your files stored in Blob Storage?  If so, your server side code can create a Shared Access Signature to allow restricted downloads.

Comment: Since the web app is being transferred from a Linux virtual server to Azure, unfortunately not, and we are looking for a way to minimize the cost. I will check into that, though, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Impact could be minimum. When a download is requested, copy the file to Blob Storage, create the SAS and create the download link.  A nightly job could clean up the files.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try and let you know, appreciate the idea!

Comment: Agree with this sentiment. Because of the limitations you've seen attempting a pure lift-and-shift, I'd suggest investing your time in app modernization (moving to Azure storage) over trying to change the code to get the old approach to work.